# Delphi open array as property index in indexed property

Tags: delphi, indexed-properties, open-array-parameters

Is it possible to use an open array as index type for indexed properties?

```
unit OpenArrayAsPropertyIndex;

interface

type

  TFoo = class
  private
    function getBar(Index: array of Integer): String;
  public
    // [DCC Error]: E2008 Incompatible types
    property Bar[Index: array of Integer]: String read getBar;
  end;

implementation

function TFoo.getBar(Index: array of Integer): String;
begin

end;

end.
```

The property getter is generated by pressing Ctl+Shift+C in the IDE, but this code doesn't compile and gives error "E2008 Incompatible types". So, is it a language limitation, or what is the correct parameter signature for the getter?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but try adding `const`.

Comment: I.e. `getBar(const Index: array of Integer)`.

Comment: Counter question: how should the code look to **use** such a property? Do you have an answer for this?

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt: "const" doesn't work, it gives the same error.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I'm just playing. But obviously it should be used as "s := Foo.Bar[[1,2,3]];"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array of Integer` use `TIntegerDynArray` from *System.Types* or a similar self declared type.

```
type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;
  TFoo = class
  private
    function getBar(Index: TIntArray): String;
  public
    property Bar[Index: TIntArray]: String read getBar;
  end;

function TFoo.getBar(Index: TIntArray): String;
begin

end;
```

Comment: `TArray<Integer>`

Comment: But this is a dynamic array, *not* an open array. (Which might be fine for the OP, considering his comment above.)

Comment: Open arrays are only allowed as parameters of procedures et al. Most likely that doesn't include indexed properties. It depends on the intended use if my answer is valid.